# Three.js (r71) - Data Initialization issue

Tags: three.js, initialization

I am getting an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.initialized')

Does someone know how to fix it? I am using three.js (r71), which has already fixed the #5831 [bug](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5831).

Comment: Can you show us the code throwing this error?

Comment: How can I put the code in a box, just like @saravanakumar did?

Comment: I don't know how to put a grey highlight with the code, so I am going to explain:  var animation = new THREE.Animation(objeto, geometry.animation); animation.play();

Comment: It's giving error on the THREE.Animation(objeto, geometry.animation) function.

Comment: Just read code formatting before ask a question? That will teach you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look directly into your json file : does `geometry.animation` exist ? `geometry.animations` more probably ? in this case it may be an array so the correct argument is `geometry.animations[0]`

Comment: No, it does not exist. There's an 'animations' array only and there is no 'geometry.animation' or 'geometry.animations'.

Comment: I precisely mean it does not exist :) the geometry is the whole json file. So you have the answer : replace `geometry.animation` with `geometry.animations[0]`

Comment: I changed to geometry.animations[0], now it's working, but the animation is not being displayed. I think the JSON file is not loading.

Comment: Do you think that the fact that JSONLoader is an asynchronous call is messing up with my program? I have read on internet issues related to it, but really not sure what is the cause of not working.

Comment: It surely is loading because otherwise you would have a 404 from the browser and from threejs. However there are 2 other mistakes in your code i did not see : - `setReceiveShadow` is `receiveShadow`, - you have to create a 'for' loop at the beginning `for(var i in materials){materials[i].skinning=true;materials[i].morphTargets=true;}`

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at that.

Comment: But I am not using morphTargets, so is it necessary to enable it?

Comment: json-asynchronous-related issues actually are about javascript, look at the console if it still does not work.

Comment: I don't know, i gave you everything you could need, remove it if it's useless

Comment: Also, there's no 'skinning' nor 'morphTargets' inside the 'materials' array. On the other hand, there are 'skinWeights' and ' skinIndices' arrays.

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you!!! I removed the materials[0].skinning = true and it worked.

Comment: Do you know what the problem might be? I have unabled the skinning, the avatar is displayed on the browser, but there is no animation.

Comment: Can you link a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Not sure how to use it

Comment: Actually, this is another code that I created, it does not contain any animation. I just want to control the rotation of bones using datGUI controls.

Comment: And FYI, I put that line ( materials[0].skinning = true ) back again and the avatar is being displayed, but still no animation.

Comment: Please link a complete jsfiddle for further comments.

Comment: I would have to upload my JSON file to a server, I don't know how to do it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Now, it's complete @Atrahasis

Comment: There is no animations data here so it is not related to your question. This is the 24th comment and none of them bring anything to the answer. I will not reply to you anymore in this discussion, ask an other question.

Answer (score 0):

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();  
loader.load( 'models/SL-MD-avatar_erica68.json', addModel );

var helpset;
function addModel( geometry,  materials ){
    materials[0].skinning = true;
    objeto= new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, new  THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    objeto.setCastShadow = true;
    objeto.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(objeto);

    helpset = new THREE.SkeletonHelper(objeto);
    helpset.visible = false;
    scene.add(helpset);

    // Instantiate the animation

    var animation = new THREE.Animation(objeto, geometry.animation);

    // Start playing the animation
    animation.play();
}
```